# Asterisk and Softone

Tags: asterisk

We have 3 different asterisks in total in 3 different buildings. We have connected them with each other via VPN and we can make calls between them and transfer calls.
We also have SoftOne setted up with queues inside it. We don’t have any queue in the asterisk at queue.conf they’re all in softone and we use some scripts to connect the two programms.

Now the problem is I want to connect two asterisk’s queues (From SoftOne) so that when the sales queue (Queue in Softone) of one building is unavailable or busy I want that call to be redirected to another building to the other queue (Which is also in SoftOne) and another asterisk.

Some people that I asked for help told me to create a rule to redirect the call if it sees that the lines are unavailable or busy.
Now I am not quite sure if that’ll be enough ( I think that rule should be at extensions.conf at TCXIN but not sure) since I think I would need and some kind of settings in Softone. Since the asterisks have different contexts I don’t know if it’s even possible to do anything in SoftOne.

Would I need to create a queue inside of asterisk’s queue.conf and put all the people I want in there, and if that’s the case can I put in an extension from another building (Asterisk) in that queue? Or is there some other setting that must be done (In extensions.conf probably?) or some Script. If any further information is required to understand my situation please ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Queue have option "leave when empty"

So if anyone busy, it will leave. After that you have check exit code and dial other building.